# How to rename all files in folder with name ending with "_backup"

Tags: command-line, bash, rename

I have a bunch of images that were somehow renamed from `myimage.jpg` to `myimage.jpg_backup`, so the images on my website don't load anymore. How would I recursively find all images ending with `_backup` and remove just the `_backup` part while preserving the rest of the filename?

I tried something like this:

```
sudo find . -name "*.jpg_backup" -exec rename -n 's/_backup$//' *.jpg_backup ';'
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Can't rename *.jpg_backup *.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

try `rename -v 's/\.jpg_backup$/\.jpg/' *.jpg_backup`
the -v gives you detail output.
see here [How to rename](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal)

Comment: i need it to be recursive though

Comment: @Edmund Just use that command in the `find`.

Answer (score 3):

In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), go to the directory where those files are (with `cd /path/to/folder`). If the files don't contain any whitespace or special characters `\[*?`, run the following command:

```bsh
for file in `find . -name *.jpg_backup` ; do mv "$file" "${file%_backup}"; done
```

If you think that you have filenames containing whitespaces or globbing characters, use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg_backup' -print0 \
| while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do mv -- "$file" "${file%_backup}"; done
```

or:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar; 
for file in /path/to/folder/**/*.jpg_backup ; do mv -- "$file" "${file%_backup}"; done
```

The above commands recursively will find all `*.jpg_backup` files from the current folder and subfolders and will rename them to `*.jpg`. The last one looks inside symbolic links to directories as well.

Comment: This will fail for filenames containing whitespace and may also fail for filenames containing glob characters. See [BashFAQ 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) on how to handle filenames safely, and [BashFAQ 30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) for safe ways to rename.

Comment: @geirha Where the OP specified that he has whitespaces in the filenames?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu The issue is that the OP did not specify he *doesn't* have any filenames with whitespace (and even if he has none now, he may have some later). Similarly, he didn't say any of his filenames have more than 18 characters or capital letters (or the letter 'q', or ...), but any solution incompatible with such filenames would be very limited. So geirha's comment is totally on-target. With that said, your recent edit should alleviate the problem.

Comment: You can replace the `mv -- "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/_backup//g')"` with `mv -- "$file" "${file%_backup}"`, which would give identical results and be pure bash (and therefore faster).

Comment: why still error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`