# Using IFS to handle whitespace in filenames

Tags: bash

In question [How to rename all files in folder with name ending with "_backup"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321963/how-to-rename-all-files-in-folder-with-name-ending-with-backup) @Radu Rădeanu gave a good answer that was useful to me as well:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg_backup' -print0 \
| while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do mv -- "$file" \
"$(echo $file | sed 's/_backup//g')"; done
```

However, I would like to fully understand his one-liner. Precisely, the part that I don't understand is:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
```

I get that IFS is "internal field separator" and I suppose this is removing or ignoring the whitespace, but I don't understand the syntax and the options.

I would also like to understand why the `--` is necessary after mv.

Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read word1 word2 … rest` does the following:

1. Read a line.
2. While the current input ends in a backslash, read another line and append it to the first one, minus the backslash-newline.
3. Break the input into separate words, where any character in the value of the `IFS` variable is considered a word separator.
4. Assign the first word to the variable `word`, the second word to the variable `word2`, etc.
5. If there are words left over, they are assigned to the variable `rest`, with the original word separators inside preserved.

The option `-r` deactivates step 2, so a `\` at the end of a line is not considered a word separator.

With `IFS` set to the empty string, there are no word separators, so the whole line is one big word: step 3 does nothing, and step 5 ends up assigning the original line to the specified variable. Regarding why `IFS` is set in this location, see [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936).

The option `-d` changes the notion of line: normally a line ends in a newline character; with `-d ''` (empty argument to `-d`), bash reads input records delimited by a null byte instead.

The upshot is that `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do …` executes the loop body for each match that `find` prints, regardless of any special characters that may occur in the file name.

---

As for the `--` in `mv -- "$file"`, it's there in case the value of `file` begins with a dash: `mv` would interpret it as an option. In this particular case, it isn't necessary, because the ouptut of this `find` command always starts with `./`. Using `--` systematically in scripts is arguably good hygiene.

---

There is a defect in this snippet: it still won't cope with file names containing whitespace or `\[?*`, because of the `"$(echo $file | sed 's/_backup//g')"` bit. A variable expansion like `$file` doesn't just substitute the value of the variable: it splits the variable into words using the value of `IFS` (just like `read` does), and treats each word as a wildcard pattern that is replaced by the list of matching files if it matches any. To avoid this behavior, write `"$file"`. This is a general shell programming rule: always put double quotes around variable substitutions (and command substitutions `$(…)` too), unless you know why you need to leave them out. (If you want the nitty-gritty, see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748); [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote/4910#4910) and [What is the significance of single and double quotes in environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/what-is-the-significance-of-single-and-double-quotes-in-environment-variables/16305#16305) may also be of interest).

The quick fix is to add the double quotes:

```
mv -- "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/_backup//g')"
```

This happens to work here because of the way the input is produced, but for general values of `file` it fails in a few rare cases:

- If the value of `file` consists of the character `-` followed by one or more letters among `Een`, then `echo` will treat it as an option and output nothing.
- Command substitution eats up the last newlines of the output, so if `$file` ends with one or more newline characters, they will be truncated.

Bash has a string substitution which can be used instead of sed here. It's more robust (you don't need to worry about subtleties with special characters) and faster.

```
mv -- "$file" "${file//_backup/}"
```

Though given what the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321963/how-to-rename-all-files-in-folder-with-name-ending-with-backup) asked for, this is the wrong operation: it removes `_backup` anywhere in the file name instead of only at the end. Here doing it right would be easier.

```
mv -- "$file" "${file%_backup}"
```

Comment: +1 for responding to the important bugs in the original script, simplifying at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, Gilles. It's very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a filename that happens to start with a hyphen, you need `--` to separate mv options from the actual filename arguments.

If you have a filename that begins or ends with spaces, that incantation of read with `IFS=` will ensure the `file` variable contains the exact filename you want.

The `-d ''` option reads zero-byte separated "lines" instead of newline separated lines -- that's because you're using find's `-print0` option.